# Pandas: Insert rows without loop

Tags: python, pandas, insert

I've seen a few answers to "inserting a row in a pandas dataframe", but they typically assume a single row insertion, or are otherwise slightly different than what I'm looking for.

I'm looking to insert into `df` a row from another dataframe multiple times, based on a condition.

The following code "works" in that it gives me what I'm looking for, but I'm wondering if this can be done without a `for` loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':[1,2,3,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,3], 
        'b':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

row_fill = pd.DataFrame({'a':[100],'b':[200]})

for i in df.index:
    if df['a'][i] == 2:
        df2 = df2.append(row_fill)

    df2 = df2.append(df.loc[i])

df2.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
df = df2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

**Source DF:**

```
In [153]: df
Out[153]:
    a  b
0   1  0
1   2  0
2   3  0
3   2  0
4   3  0
5   1  0
6   1  0
7   2  0
8   1  0
9   2  0
10  3  0
11  3  0
12  1  0
13  3  0
```

**Solution:**

```
In [154]: idx = np.argwhere(df.a == 2) # Pandas alternative: idx = df.index[df.a == 2]

In [155]: new = pd.concat([row_fill] * len(idx)).set_index(idx-1)

In [156]: new
Out[156]:
     a    b
0  100  200
2  100  200
6  100  200
8  100  200
```

The same can be achieved using DataFrame constructor:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(row_fill.values.tolist() * len(idx), 
                   columns=row_fill.columns, index=idx-1)
```

now we can concatenate `df` and `new`, sort index in the resulting DF and reset the index:

```
In [157]: res = pd.concat([df, new]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

In [158]: res
Out[158]:
      a    b
0     1    0
1   100  200
2     2    0
3     3    0
4   100  200
5     2    0
6     3    0
7     1    0
8     1    0
9   100  200
10    2    0
11    1    0
12  100  200
13    2    0
14    3    0
15    3    0
16    1    0
17    3    0
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU - I'm just thinking through this right now.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with numpy.  But obviously it works!

Comment: @pshep123, you are welcome :) If you don't like Numpy, we can use: `idx = df.index[df.a == 2]` instead

Comment: This is great, thanks again @MaxU.  I broke down the last `.concat()` function just to see what was going on.  Is it because the `df` is first in that `.concat()` that it goes ahead of `new` despite the fact that they have the same index?

Comment: @pshep123, yep :)

Comment: @MaxU if I wanted to add two rows using  new = pd.DataFrame(row_fill.values.tolist() * len(idx),  columns=row_fill.columns, index=idx-1), how do I increase the indices to give me idx-1 and idx+1. I know I can increase the columns but have issues increasing index to match the columns. Thanks in advance.